# How to make four-way logarithmic plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

Four-way logarithmic plot is a very often used graph for vibration control and earthquake protection. How can this plot be plotted in MATLAB
instead of adding axes in Inkscape?

A sample of four-way logarithmic plot is here:

[image]

Comment: The MathWorks forums have a bunch of unanswered questions on how to make tripartite plots, I too am frustrated that there is not an out-of-the-box Matlab solution for this! It's also [not implemented in Matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/343/) for Python.